# Dynamics 2011 (IFD) CRM SOAP Update not working

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am using PHP to connect to a Dynamics 2011 IFD and successfully authenticating and retrieving contacts to my web application.

I am however struggling to update a contact.

My SOAP request (below) is returning 'Bad Request' and unfortunately I do not have sufficient admin access to the server to enable more useful error reporting. Can anyone spot anything obvious in this XML which may be the issue?

```
$request = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          '.$this->crmAuth->GetSoapHeaderOnPremise("Update").'
        <s:Body>
            <Update xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
                <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>contactid</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">'.$contactid.'</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>firstname</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'.$firstname.'</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>lastname</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'.$lastname.'</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                </a:Attributes>
                <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
                <a:FormattedValues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
                <a:Id>'.$contactid.'</a:Id>
                <a:LogicalName>contact</a:LogicalName>
                <a:RelatedEntities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
              </entity>
            </Update>
          </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>'
```

The 'getSoapHeaderOnPremise' function is returning working auth headers for the retrieve/retrieveMultiple requests. The only difference here being the Update method being specified:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Update</a:Action>
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is a wild guess, not having performed an update like this myself.*

Remove this bit,

```
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>contactid</b:key>
     <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">'.$contactid.'</b:value>
</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

This suggests you are trying set the record id field, which isn't something you normally do.

You have this bit which would seem to associate your update to a single record, so I suspect the above is not required.

```
<a:Id>'.$contactid.'</a:Id>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply - sadly it didn't make any difference though. Good suggestion. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but it looks like there is a [project on Git](https://github.com/epinapala/MsDynamicsPHP) to deal with this.

Comment: That looks to be for connecting to the hosted live.com versions of Dynamics, but I'll certainly have a look through the code and double check no clues there. Thanks.